# PSE Advent Calendar 2021 (Day 5): Christmas Shopping

Tags: visual, rebus, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling StackExchange Advent Calendar 2021](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 100 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112909) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112939)</sub>

---

What do we need to buy for our glorious Christmas dinner? Create a shopping list of all the things to get by deciphering the rebus puzzle.
*Bonus question:* Find out what is broken and needs to be replaced.

[image: rebus puzzle]

Answer (score 10):

<sub>Thanks to a comment from 1357924680a this puzzle from 2021 is now fully solved.</sub>

1)

> One kilo of beef or pork
> NO symbol backwards + (+1 = LIKE) backwards + O = ONE KILO. off=OF. bbbb=b4=BEEF OR. Morse code P + double bar OR operator, and Morse code disguised as a smiley face K = PORK.
> h/t M Oehm, somebody & LOTGP

2. 

> Nine fish
> N in E F is H.

3. 

> Two new veneer chairs
> toe=two, gnu=new. ve<->=ve near=veneer. ch + “air” + s = chairs.
> h/t M Oehm, somebody & No Name

4. 

> Eight pounds of potatoes
> Eat past tense is ate or EIGHT. p oz = p ounce which sounds like POUNDS. Cuff (nosy = no C) = uff or OF. POT + A + arrow TO + (español - pañol (spanish for store-room) = ES) = POTATOES.
> h/t M Oehm, somebody, user168715 & 1357924680a

5. 

> A bone to give the dog
> LANRETE with backwards arrow under it spells ETERNAL. It is colored like the Swedish flag. Swedish for 'eternal' is 'evig'. 'Evig' backwards is 'give'. There is an A bound to it. Word THE is THE. The flags are semaphores for the letters D O G. A bound to give the dog.
> h/t M Oehm & somebody

6. 

> Many vegetables
> Person whose head is male symbol = MAN. A Y on him makes MANY. V-edge tables = vegetables.
> h/t M Oehm

7. 

> Dozen sugar canes
> Someone taking a doze, his snores are Ns instead of Zs. The backwards flag of US is SU. The coordinates point to a town in Brazil called Garca. Adding that to the Loch Ness Monster (Nessie) and subtracting ie (internet explorer) and respacing yields DOZEN SUGAR CANES(S)
> h/t M Oehm & somebody

8. 

> Ten puddings
> Tungsten - tongues (puddle rings) - ruler’s 3rd 4th and 5th letters.

9. 

> Forty cookies
> Four ties Braile C O O keys.

Comment: Very good. Some more ideas in rot13 for maximum pre-Christmas secrecy: (1) Cerggl fher vg fgnegf jvgu "bar xvyb bs S...: "ab" naq "yvxr" onpxjneqf + bss. (3) Jung pbzrf orsber gur "ab anhgvpny fgberebbz" vf "cbgngb". (5) Rgreany vf Fjrqvfu vf rivt. Gurer'f nyfb na N punvarq gb gung. Tvir punva gb qbt? Uz. (6) Fheryl gurfr ner I-rqtr gnoyrf. (7) Gur VR zhfg or erzbirq sebz Arffvr. Ab vqrn nobhg gur ortvaavat, gubhtu.

Comment: more ideas: (1) oooo znl or "oo dhrhr", ohg ea vgf n fgergpu. (5) znlor gur jbeqvat vf "n punva? gb tvir gur qbt" (4) ... cnpzna, oebjfre uvfgbel vpba... pnc c bhapr??? vs gur ebgngvba vf gnxra zber yvgrenyyl... q bm (ra)? sbe "anhgvpny fgberebbz", znevan xvaqn pbhagf, naq vf inthryl sbbq eryngrq (3) gur navzny vf n jvyqrorrfg. gur nafjre pbhyq or "srfgvir punvef" ohg ntnva n fgergpu ngz. gur neebjf zvtug uryc, gurl zvtug pbqr sbe nabgure jbeq. (7) gung ybbxf yvxr gur hf gjvggre rzbwv, juvpu onpxjneqf jbhyq or whfg "fh"

Comment: @somebody a jvyqrorrfg is also called a tah, just fyi

Comment: @MOehm haha (I-rqtr gnoyrf) made my day. Everything else looks really good too. Nice work on lanrete.

Comment: @somebody Very nice. I think (oo dhrhr) is exactly right. Other ideas look good too.

Comment: hm. (4) abfl = ab p? juvpu znl ghea phss vagb hss? uvfgbel + cnpzna = onpx cnp???? abg n dhnagvsvre. (3) gbr tah = gjb arj??????

Comment: @somebody Very nice! rot13(hss pbhyq = bs, fb znlor k bm bs. Naq gjb arj kk punvef pbhyq or "jung vf oebxra naq arrqf gb or ercynprq")

Comment: v qhaab ubj ohg gur guvat nsgre cbgngb vf cebonoyl fnynq

Comment: (3) rot13(ir... nebhaq??? = ir enaqn? jub xabjf.)

Comment: so right now it seems (4) and (7) still have the most work to do?

Comment: I think 5 is just rot13(n obar gb tvir gur qbt -- "N obhaq gb ...") and 3 might be rot13(gjb arj _fbzrguvat_ punvef). Oh, and 7 is rot13("n qbmra fhtnepnarf -- n qbmr + A + jung'f nyernql gurer).

Comment: Idea for 3): rot13(Qbhoyr neebjf pbhyq zrna ov-qverpgvbany, znlor whfg "ov")

Comment: @Crimsonfox maybe... but not sure if/how that would fit into the phrase

Comment: Not seen it mentioned yet, but I think the symbol at the end of 4 is rot13(n ab ragel fvta (zber pbzzbayl frra jvgu n juvgr fgevcr, ohg fbzr pbhagevrf hfr lryybj), fb V jbhyq thrff jr ner ybbxvat sbe n genafyngvba bs "ab ragel" jvgu fbzrguvat erzbirq sbe gur anhgvpny fgberebbz) . But I haven't found a way to make that work yet.

Comment: Let me give you a few hints: 1) “BBQ pork” isn’t what I was thinking about, although it makes sense. How many b’s are there? 3) Take a look at the length of the arrow – I could have made it longer. 4) What does an open mouth signify? Also, you’ll probably need a dictionary.

Comment: (3) rot13(ir arne = irarre) of course... heh, not sure why i didn't think of that earlier. (1)... the clue gets me rot13(orsber) but not convinced that helps. (4) is still eluding me too. hopefully someone else can figure them out

Comment: It is unclear if Lypyrhythm will come back to PSE, therefore: If this doesn't get fully solved (in case it's even possible to know its the correct solution when you have it) until 12/24, I'll award the 100 point bounty to this answer regardless.

Comment: (4) is probably something like rot13(rvtug cbhaqf bs cbgngb gbegvyyn (ngr c bhapr hss cbg n gb (???) gvyyn)). But I don't understand how the crossing-out turns into that missing syllable.

Comment: (1) what about rot13(orrs be cbex, nf o4 -> osbhe -> orrs be)

Comment: @user168715 i saw that a while ago and thought it was too much of a stretch but upon further thinking... rot13(tvira gung vg'f va tnyvpvna, juvpu vf "n pb-bssvpvny ynathntr jvgu fcnavfu" va n ertvba ba fcnva) it makes a lot more sense. also because, perhaps surprisingly, rot13(cbgngb gbegvyyn vf na npghny (fcnavfu!) qvfu). of course the final piece of the puzzle seem to still elude us...

Comment: @cap for (4) it seems like you may be missing the explanation for the cuff symbol

Comment: @cap it seems that you are overcomplicating yourself. What is the Spanish word for Spanish?

Comment: @1357924680a nice catch. We can finally wrap this one up. Thank you.