# PSE Advent Calendar 2021 (Day 7): Don't forget the lyrics!

Tags: crosswords, music, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling StackExchange Advent Calendar 2021](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/112939/60644) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112982)</sub>

---

In the following snowflake-shaped crossword puzzle, 44 words can be filled in by solving straightforward crossword clues (listed below).  The remaining spaces are to be filled with words appearing in a (well known) mystery Christmas song whose (partial) lyrics are reproduced below the clue list, with unclued words replaced by 'BLANK'. Line breaks have been removed from the song excerpt to disguise it further.

> **TASK:** Fully resolve the crossword puzzle, and deduce and name the associated Christmas song.

[image: Snowflake-shaped crossword]

**Across (A):**
3. Fruit with a tough shell (3)
19. In good physical condition (3)
23. Faucet (3)
24. Sweet potato (3)
27. Hawaiian island (4)
36. Moose (3)
43. Adhesive (4)
44. Cap, for a jar (e.g.) (3)
46. Taxi (3)
48. Parabola (3)
59. Not closed (4)
60. Apiece (4)
61. Positive response (3)

**Down & Left (DL):**
5. Squall, or flurry (4)
11. Small, green vegetable (3)
13. Break, split (4)
14. Cereal plant (3)
23. Noise of displeasure? (3)
29. Unit of resistance (3)
31. Domesticated ox (3)
39. Ukrainian Gunner, Luzhny (4)
41. Sphere (3)
50. Belonging to him (3)
51. Fresh (3)
54. French cheese (4)

**Down & Right (DR):**
1. Pale (3)
4. Numbers between 12 and 20? (5)
9. Bird’s home (4)
10. Number of seats on a tandem (3)
12. Butter commonly used in cosmetics (4)
16. Up to this moment (3)
20. Creator of *Tom Sawyer* (5)
22. Pair (3)
26. Crème-filled biscuit brand (4)
28. Noise of disgust? (3)
32. Veracious (4)
35. Bovine utterance (3)
37. Beer barrel (3)
42. Historical age (3)
45. Lair (3)
47. Baby's dinnertime protection? (3)
49. Vegetable, pak ____ (4)
52. Precedes 'drome', 'plane' and 'dynamic' (4)
55. South American capital (4)

**MYSTERY SONG:**

> BLANK **[30DR]** **[15DL]** **[33DL]** BLANK **[34DL]** BLANK **[8DL]** **[53DR]** BLANK **[21A]** BLANK **[61DL]** **[6DR]** **[62DR]** BLANK **[61DL]** BLANK **[7A]** **[58DR]** BLANK **[56A]** **[48DL]** BLANK **[30DR]** **[14A]** BLANK **[40A]** BLANK **[38DR]** **[21A]** BLANK **[34A]** **[51A]** BLANK **[3DL]** **[2DL]** BLANK BLANK BLANK BLANK **[18DR]** BLANK **[56DL]** BLANK **[41A]** BLANK BLANK **[36DL]** **[17A]** **[46DL]** BLANK **[58DR]** BLANK **[57DL]** **[31A]** BLANK BLANK BLANK **[25DL]** **[61DL]** BLANK BLANK BLANK BLANK BLANK **[50A]** **[30DR]** BLANK BLANK **[34A]** BLANK BLANK BLANK **[29A]** **[57DL]** **[5A]** BLANK **[30DR]** **[15DL]** **[33DL]** BLANK **[24DL]** BLANK BLANK BLANK BLANK

Comment: 2 should be DL?

Comment: @durron597 Indeed, well spotted. Now fixed, thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Christmas song we're looking for is:

> [Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolph_the_Red-Nosed_Reindeer_(song)), written by Johnny Marks and recorded by a number of artists.

The solved crossword:

> [image: crw]
>  Across (A):
>  3. Fruit with a tough shell (3) NUT
>  19. In good physical condition (3) FIT
>  23. Faucet (3) TAP
>  24. Sweet potato (3) YAM
>  27. Hawaiian island (4) OAHU
>  36. Moose (3) ELK
>  43. Adhesive (4) GLUE
>  44. Cap, for a jar (e.g.) (3) LID
>  46. Taxi (3) CAB
>  48. Parabola (3) ARC
>  59. Not closed (4) OPEN
>  60. Apiece (4) EACH
>  61. Positive response (3) YES
>  
>  Down & Left (DL):
>  5. Squall, or flurry (4) GUST
>  11. Small, green vegetable (3) PEA
>  13. Break, split (4) SNAP
>  14. Cereal plant (3) OAT
>  23. Noise of displeasure? (3) TUT
>  29. Unit of resistance (3) OHM
>  31. Domesticated ox (3) YAK
>  39. Ukrainian Gunner, Luzhny (4) OLEG
>  41. Sphere (3) ORB
>  50. Belonging to him (3) HIS
>  51. Fresh (3) NEW
>  54. French cheese (4) BRIE
>  
>  Down & Right (DR):
>  1. Pale (3) WAN
>  4. Numbers between 12 and 20? (5) TEENS
>  9. Bird’s home (4) NEST
>  10. Number of seats on a tandem (3) TWO
>  12. Butter commonly used in cosmetics (4) SHEA
>  16. Up to this moment (3) YET
>  20. Creator of Tom Sawyer (5) TWAIN
>  22. Pair (3) DUO
>  26. Crème-filled biscuit brand (4) OREO
>  28. Noise of disgust? (3) UGH
>  32. Veracious (4) TRUE
>  35. Bovine utterance (3) MOO
>  37. Beer barrel (3) KEG
>  42. Historical age (3) ERA
>  45. Lair (3) DEN
>  47. Baby's dinnertime protection? (3) BIB
>  49. Vegetable, pak ____ (4) CHOI
>  52. Precedes 'drome', 'plane' and 'dynamic' (4) AERO
>  55. South American capital (4) LIMA

Filling in the letters in the correct places, leads to:

> BLANK [..e] [..d] [n...d] BLANK [h..] BLANK [...y] [..i.y]
>  BLANK [a.d] BLANK [y..] [....] [s..] BLANK [y..] BLANK
>  [e..n] [s..] BLANK [..o..] [a.l] BLANK [..e] [oth..] BLANK
>  [u...] BLANK [..u..] [a.d] BLANK [h.m] [na...] BLANK [n....] [..t]
>  BLANK BLANK BLANK BLANK [a.y] BLANK [..m.s] BLANK [o..]
>  BLANK BLANK [e..] [s..ta] [c..e] BLANK [s..] BLANK [.i.h]
>  [y..r] BLANK BLANK BLANK [w..t] [y..] BLANK BLANK BLANK BLANK
>  BLANK [h..] [..e] BLANK BLANK [h.m] BLANK BLANK BLANK [o.t]
>  [.i.h] [g...] BLANK [..e] [..d] [n...d] BLANK [yo...] BLANK
>  BLANK BLANK BLANK

Then:

> Realizing that [s..ta] must be 'Santa' and [..e] [..d] [n...d] (occurring twice!) must be 'the red nosed', we can gradually find more and more words:
>  BLANK [the] [red] [nosed] BLANK [had] BLANK [very] [shiny]
>  BLANK [and] BLANK [you] [ever] [saw] BLANK [you] BLANK
>  [even] [say] BLANK [glows] [all] BLANK [the] [other] BLANK
>  [used] BLANK [laugh] [and] BLANK [him] [names] BLANK [never] [let]
>  BLANK BLANK BLANK BLANK [any] BLANK [games] BLANK [one]
>  BLANK BLANK [eve] [santa] [came] BLANK [say] BLANK [with]
>  [your] BLANK BLANK BLANK [won't] [you] BLANK BLANK BLANK BLANK
>  BLANK [how] [the] BLANK BLANK [him] BLANK BLANK BLANK [out]
>  [with] [glee] BLANK [the] [red] [nosed] BLANK [you'll)] BLANK
>  BLANK BLANK BLANK

This leads to the full lyrics of the song:

> Rudolph the red-nosed reindeer
>  Had a very shiny nose
>  And if you ever saw it
>  You would even say it glows
>  All of the other reindeer
>  Used to laugh and call him names
>  They never let poor Rudolph
>  Play in any reindeer games
>  Then one foggy Christmas Eve
>  Santa came to say
>  Rudolph with your nose so bright
>  Won't you guide my sleigh tonight?
>  Then how the reindeer loved him
>  As they shouted out with glee
>  Rudolph the red-nosed reindeer
>  You'll go down in history!

Comment: Well done :) Indeed correct!