# PSE Advent Calendar 2021 (Day 9): Christmas songs in emoji

Tags: music, seasonal, emoji

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling StackExchange Advent Calendar 2021](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112982)[<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/113011/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-10-the-distracted-gridsmith)</sub>

---

Below are 40 parts of lyrics taken from well known Christmas songs.

Your job is to identify 20 songs, each of which contains 2 lines in the list below.

Good luck

[image: christmas_emoji]

Hint 1:

> 3 and 18 are from the same song.

Hint 2:

> 4 and 14 are from the same song.

Hint 3:

> 7 and 26 are from the same song.

Comment: The line between 6 and 7 and the line between 7 and 8 are both part of 7, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All answers, combined from answers/comments + my own additions, but I'm not sure about 4/14 because of "joyful emoji" in 4...

> 1 Can you Stop the Cavalry? **Stop the Cavalry**
>  2 Let's hope it's a good one without any fear **Happy Xmas (War is Over)** (Stiv!)
>  3 It doesn't show signs of stopping **Let It Snow**
>  4 So I pray and I wait (**Why Couldn't It Be Christmas Everyday?** *(hesitant about this one, but wait = looking at hourglass)*
>  5 The moon and stars seem awful cold and bright **Thank God It's Christmas**
>  6 Don't let the bells end **Christmas Time (Don't Let the Bells End)**
>  7 Rocking around the Christmas Tree **Rocking Around the Christmas Tree**
>  8 Eight little reindeer pull his sleigh **Must Be Santa**
>  9 There'll be scary ghost stories **It's the Most Wonderful Time of the Year** Thanks CAP!
>  10 And there won't be snow in Africa this Christmas time **Do They Know It's Christmas?**
>  11 Dolls that'll talk and will go for a walk **It's Beginning to Look a Lot Like Christmas**
>  12 I got red lights all around **Driving Home For Christmas**
>  13 ...around the coffee and the pumpkin pie **Sleigh Ride**
>  14 There's a gift for every girl and boy **Why Couldn't It Be Christmas Everyday?**
>  15 Presents, what a beautiful sight **Underneath the Tree**
>  16 Let's stop all the fight. **Happy Xmas (War is Over)** (Stiv!)
>  17 Wish I could be dancing now In the arms of the girl I love **Stop the Cavalry**
>  18 He's sitting by the fire's cosy glow **Let It Snow**
>  19 Who's got a big red cherry nose **Must be Santa**
>  20 When he sees your Mama kissin' Santa Claus? **Merry Xmas Everybody**
>  21 He knows if you've been bad or good **Here Comes Santa Claus**
>  22 Driving Home for Christmas **Driving Home For Christmas**
>  23 Jingle bell time is a swell time **Jingle Bell Rock**
>  24 The Ox and Lamb kept time **Little Drummer Boy**
>  25 A pair of Hopalong boots and a pistol that shoots **It's Beginning to Look a Lot Like Christmas**
>  26 Mistletoe hung where you can see **Rocking Around the Christmas Tree**
>  27 Lovely weather for a sleigh ride together with you **Sleigh Ride**
>  28 Let's hope the snow will make this Christmas right **Thank God it's Christmas**
>  29 I won't even stay awake to hear those magic reindeer click **All I Want for Christmas is You**
>  30 He sees you when you're sleeping **Here Comes Santa Claus**
>  31 All of the other reindeer used to laugh and call him names **Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer**
>  32 On the 25th day of the 12th month The sleigh bells are in time ringing true **Christmas Time (Don't Let the Bells End)**
>  33 Where nothing ever grows; No rain nor rivers flow **Do They Know It's Christmas?**
>  34 Do the fairies keep him sober for a day? **Merry Xmas Everybody**
>  35 What a bright time, it's the right time **Jingle Bell Rock**
>  36 Shall I play for him? **Little Drummer Boy**
>  37 Christmas was cold and grey **Underneath the Tree**
>  38 I just wanna see my baby standing right outside my door **All I Want For Christmas is You**
>  39 Then one foggy Christmas Eve Santa came to say... "Rudolph, with your nose so bright, won't you guide my sleigh tonight?" **Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer**
>  40 Hearts will be glowing **It's the Most Wonderful Time of the Year**

Comment: This is the complete and correct list, well done!

Answer (score 8):

5 left.  Post your own wrap up post if you can find them. I'm done until tomorrow.

> 1 Can you Stop the Cavalry? (Stop the Cavalry)
>  2 Let's hope it's a good one without any fear (Happy Christmas the war is over) (Stiv!)
>  3 ??? Every couple tries to stop (Rocking around the Christmas Tree)
>  4
>  5 The moon and stars seem awful cold and bright (Thank God it's Christmas)
>  6 Don't let the bells end (Christmas Time)
>  7 Rocking around the Christmas Tree (Rocking around the Christmas Tree)
>  8 Eight little reindeer pull his sleigh (Must Be Santa)
>  9 There'll be scary ghost stories (Most wonderful time ...) Thanks CAP!
>  10  And there won't be snow in Africa this Christmas time (Do They Know it's Christmas)
>  11 Dolls that'll talk and will go for a walk (It's Beginning..)
>  12 I got red lights all around,(Driving Home For Christmas)
>  13 ... around the coffee and the pumpkin pie (Sleigh Ride)
>  14
>  15 Presents, what a beautiful sight (Underneath the Tree)
>  16 Let's stop all the fight. (Happy Christmas the war is over)(Stiv!)
>  17 Wish I could be dancing now In the arms of the girl I love (Stop the Cavalry)
>  18
>  19 Who's got a big red cherry nose (Must be Santa)
>  20 ... daddy had only seen Mommy kissing Santa Claus... (I saw mommy kissing Santa Claus)
>  21 He knows if you've been bad or good (Here comes Santa Claus)
>  22 Driving Home for Christmas (Driving Home for Christmas)
>  23 Jingle bell time is a swell time (Jingle Bell Rock)
>  24 The Ox and Lamb kept time (Little Drummer Boy)
>  25 A pair of Hopalong boots and a pistol that shoots (It's beginning to look a lot like Christmas)
>  26 Mistletoe hung where you can see (Rocking around the Christmas Tree)
>  27 Lovely weather for a sleigh ride together with you (Sleigh Ride)
>  28 Let's hope the snow will make this Christmas right (Thank God it's Christmas)
>  29 I won't even stay awake to hear those magic reindeer click (The Forbidden Song)
>  30 He sees you when you're sleeping (Here comes Santa Claus)
>  31 All of the other reindeer used to laugh and call him names (Rudolph)
>  32 On the 25th day of the 12th month The sleigh bells are in time ringing true (Christmas Time)
>  33 Where nothing ever grows No rain nor rivers flow (Do They Know it's Christmas)
>  34
>  35 What a bright time, it's the right time (Jingle Bell rock)
>  36 Shall I Play for him? (Little Drummer Boy)
>  37 Christmas was cold and grey (Underneath the tree)
>  38 I just wanna see my baby standing right outside my door (The Forbidden Song)
>  39 Then one foggy Christmas Eve Santa came to say... "Rudolph, with your nose so bright Won't you guide my sleigh tonight?" (Rudolph)
>  40 ...hearts will be glowing (Most Wonderful time of the year)

Comment: 9 is rot13("Gurer'yy or fpnel tubfg fgbevrf" sebz "Vg’f gur Zbfg Jbaqreshy Gvzr bs gur Lrne"). 4 might be the title of that song.

Comment: Thanks for 9... It's partner is 40.

Comment: Wow, you've got most of them now! All that's left for me to contribute for you is rot13(Lbhe 2 fubhyq or 6, orpnhfr 2=Yrg’f ubcr vg’f n tbbq bar, jvgubhg nal srne & 16=Yrg’f fgbc nyy gur svtug (obgu sebz Unccl Kznf (Jne vf Bire) ol Wbua Yraaba & Lbxb Bab) 26 znl or 'Zvfgyrgbr uhat jurer lbh pna frr' sebz Ebpxvat Nebhaq gur Puevfgznf Gerr vs lbh pna yrtvgvzvfr 'uhat' urer)

Comment: @Stiv You're right. That is the rot13(unat ybbfr fvta)

Comment: Yeah... that was an edit mistake on my part.

Comment: And I read the lyrics to Lennon about 10 times and it didn't stick!

Comment: @Stiv good call on 26

Comment: Oh, I've totally just spotted 34 and can't believe I hadn't seen it: rot13("Qb gur snvevrf xrrc uvz fbore sbe n qnl?" sebz Fynqr'f Zreel Kznf Rirelobql. Tvira gur arj uvag, guvf zrnaf gung vg cnvef jvgu rvgure 4 be 14. Va juvpu pnfr 4 zvtug whfg or 'Ybbx gb gur shgher...'? Nygreangviryl 14 zvtug or 'rirelobql'f univat sha' - pubvprf, pubvprf!!)

Comment: rot13(Npghnyyl, 14 fubhyq or gnxra dhvgr yvgrenyyl naq vg cnvef jvgu 4.)

Comment: Your #3 can't be right, since it would make 3 lines from the same song.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the easier ones, but I figured out:

> 7:  Rockin' around the Christmas tree  (Rockin' around the Christmas Tree)
> 20: I saw mommy kissing Santa Claus (I saw mommy kissing Santa Claus)
> 21: He knows if you've been bad or good  (Here comes Santa Claus)
> 24: The ox and lamb kept time (Little Drummer Boy)
> 25: A pair of Hopalong boots and a pistol that shoots  (It's beginning to look a lot like Christmas)
> 27: Lovely weather for a sleigh ride together with you (Sleigh Ride)
> 30: He sees you when you're sleeping (Here comes Santa Claus)
> 31: All of the other reindeer used to laugh and call him names (Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer)
> 36: Shall I play for him? (Little Drummer Boy)
> 39: Then one foggy Christmas Even Santa came to say Rudolph with your nose so bright won't you guide my sleigh tonight? (Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer)

Comment: Nice! 11 is rot13(Qbyyf gung'yy gnyx naq jvyy tb sbe n jnyx)

Comment: Also 23 is rot13(wvatyr oryy gvzr vf n fjryy gvzr)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Hint #1,

> #3 and #18 are both from "Let it Snow"

> 3)  = It doesn't show signs of stopping.

> 18)  = He's sitting by the fire's cosy glow