# PSE Advent Calendar 2021 (Day 21): How the Grinch Trolled Quizmas

Tags: steganography, poetry, seasonal, humor

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling StackExchange Advent Calendar 2021](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114146/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-20-candy-cane-sudoku)
[<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114160/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-22-quick-math-card)</sub>

---

Some of the puzzles have been pretty crazy.
Here’s a simpler one for the eager but lazy:

---

**How the Grinch Trolled Quizmas**

> Well, each Clu in Clueville liked puzzles a lot,
> but the Grinch, who lived next to Clueville, did NOT!
> The Grinch hated Puzzles; the whole Exchanged Stack!
> Regardless of hardness of mystery to crack.
> Venom for riddles! Hatred for brain-teasers!
> And cryptics—and limericks—and ciphers of Caesar's!
> Each affix? Each matrix? The match-sticks? The weigh-tricks?
> Odium! Sodium! Since nigh advent day-six!
> And some say the reason he chose not to solve 'em
> was all through the season Clus didn’t involve him.
> Each puzzle, brand new, set by puzzling free-lancers?
> 'Twas solved by a Clu before Grinchy had answers.
> Then he got an idea! An awful idea!
> The Grinch got a wonderful awful idea!
> "Now here’s what I'll do," he said with resolution.
> "They'll all get a puzzle that has no solution!"
> Yucking and chuckling, "What a great Grinchy ruse!"
> "An impossible puzzle to fool all the Clus,
> with pure balderdash to turn solvers to quitters!”
> He wrote like a flash with four laughs and two titters.
> “Rote cliché, with word-play, and perfect logicians!
> And Morse code, and graph-nodes, and dual definitions!
> A big fat red herring!  A lie of omissions!
> I'll keep those Clus erring with bad suppositions."
> On finishing typing he surveyed his writing
> with a title he, vitally, had made exciting,
> and voicing the whole mess, he watched his creation.
> Rejoicing (in excess) as it earned reputation.
> "Right now they are finding no answer will come!"
> "They are all giving up! They're all saying *'I'm dumb!'*"
> He refreshed the page and he stared at his screen
> 'Til he DID find a response that dared to be seen…
> Yes, ‘twas apropos—yes ‘twas quite unassailable!
> The *answer,* although, he'd thought none were available.
> It came without hints! It came without tags!
> Edits or comments, or Reddit or flags!
> "Yet this cannot be-" he began to implore,
> then the Grinch thought of something he hadn't before.
> "Maybe puzzles," he thought, "aren't about a *score.*"
> "Each puzzle... perhaps... is for *all* to adore!"
> For what happened next? Well, in Clueville they say,
> the Grinch went and tried EVERY puzzle that day!
> He worked on each one! Every quiz in Clu-County!
> Now he, HIMSELF, The Grinch! Is awarding you bounty.

---

The simple hidden message in this Christmas Fable is:

`_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _`

Merry Quizmas PSE :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, the first thing one might notice -- and, credit where due, Jeremy Dover noticed this before I even saw the puzzle, in an answer now deleted, so if you like this answer go and upvote something worthy of his! -- is that

> the *first* letter of the *last* line of each stanza, taken in order of appearance, yields the mystical message ROT-THIRTEEN.

Is this the Answer? No! Looking around for things to apply it to, we see that

> the *first* letter of the *first* line of each stanza, taken in order of appearance, yields the even more mystical message WVATYRORYYF, which on ROT13ing yields: **JINGLE BELLS**.

Incidentally, I enjoyed the Dr Seuss parody very much.

Comment: *"I do not like this Christmas riddle, I do not like it with a fiddle..."* Only joking, this one is awesome.