# PSE Advent Calendar 2021 (Day 23): Gee, I Really Wonder Where We'll Land

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-crosswords, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling StackExchange Advent Calendar 2021](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114160/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-22-quick-math-card) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/114197/28719)</sub>

---

To fully solve this puzzle (and receive the bounty!), find a magical place to be with these sorts of characters after solving the cryptic crossword.

*Please forgive the less-than-acceptable checking, and I hope that all the clues are fair and legal. Merry Christmas Eve Eve, and Happy Holidays to all!*

[image: cryptic crossword grid]

| Across | Down |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Last drops of gin and tonic among their snacks for movie (3,11) | 1. Show busy teachers around ferry (3,4,5) |
| 7. Philosopher considered keynote after angry letter about doctor with Omicron (14) | 2. I care about *Stranger Things* character (5) |
| 10. Headerless programming language with archive file and icon (6) | 3. Curtailed fish? Back to meat alternative (3) |
| 12. King's core of three back in a fantastic place (6) | 4. Picked up pace to tourist destination (4) |
| 13. Host from Norway ushered in by the Spanish and the French (5) | 5. RPG from alert broadcast found in summit (9) |
| 15. Tools are finally silent around noon and in the afternoon (9) | 6. Start petition now (5) |
| 17. Snow Queen banished a creature protecting her abroad (9) | 8. According to Spooner, all of us plant algae (7) |
| 18. Regularly avoid due to recording (5) | 9. Without notice, sign follows need for books (12) |
| 19. Oceanic country not essential to Japanese city (6) | 11. Attorney general supported by current Vice President (5) |
| 21. Two articles and novella exhausted wise woman? (6) | 14. Soviet scientist put bits of eggplant and nutmeg in scrambled yolks (7) |
| 24. Game or conversation boring Mother, Billy, Iota, and yours truly (6,6,2) | 15. Discussions following electronic agreement lead to natural protrusions (9) |
| 26. America returning broken Mars probes filled with gas to Sweden becomes game (5,5,4.) | 16. Turn to celebrity head over heels (5) |
|  | 20. Hear about bathing time early in the morning (5) |
|  | 22. Return from garden terrace (5) |
|  | 23. Epilogue is improvised, written up without heart (4) |
|  | 25. Scrooge says, "This party? Pointless!" |

[image: An image with blanks as followed: the blanks are black unless stated to be blue. The first line is a six-letter word with the last letter blue. The second line is a six-letter word with the first letter blue, followed by a seven-letter word with the third letter blue. The third line is a three-letter word connected to a four-letter word with a hyphen; the letter after the hyphen is blue. The fourth line is a three-letter word, then two five-letter words; the third letter of the second word is blue. The fifth line is a four-letter word with a blue second letter. The sixth line is a three-letter word with a blue first letter, followed by an eight-letter word with a blue fifth letter. The seventh line is two nine-letter words; the second letter of the first word and the fourth of the second are blue. The last line is seven-letter word with a blue fourth letter.]

## Grid Transcription

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 2 |  | 3 |  | 4 |  | 5 |  | 6 |  |  |  | ■ |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ | ■ |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 8 |  | ■ |
|  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | 9 |
| 10 |  |  |  | 11 |  | ■ | 12 |  |  |  |  |  | ■ |  |
|  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 13 |  | 14 |  |  | ■ | 15 |  |  |  | 16 |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 17 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ■ | 18 |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  |
|  | ■ | 19 |  | 20 |  |  |  | ■ | 21 |  |  | 22 |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | 23 | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| ■ | 24 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 25 |  |  |  |  |
| ■ | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| ■ | 26 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, here's the solved cryptic crossword:

> [image: Solved crossword]

Clue explanations:

> **Across:**
>  1. Last drops of gin and tonic among their snacks for **movie** (3,11) **THE INCREDIBLES** = THEI((-gi)N + (-toni)C)R + EDIBLES
>  7. **Philosopher** considered keynote after angry letter about doctor with Omicron (14) **EPISTEMOLOGIST** = EPISTLE* around MO (Medical Officer) + O (Omicron) + GIST (keynote)
>  10. Headerless programming language with archive file and **icon** (6) **AVATAR** = (-j)AVA + [TAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing))
>  12. King's core of three back in a **fantastic place** (6) **NARNIA** = (-mo)NAR(-ch) + IN< + A
>  13. **Host** from Norway ushered in by the Spanish and the French (5) **[ELLEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellen_DeGeneres)** = EL + LE + N (Norway)
>  15. **Tools** are finally silent around noon and in the afternoon (9) **EQUIPMENT** = (-ar)E + QUI(PM)ET around N (Noon)
>  17. Snow Queen banished a creature protecting her **abroad** (9) **ELSEWHERE** = ELS(-a) + EW(HER)E
>  18. Regularly avoid due to **recording** (5) **VIDEO** = (-a)V(-o)I(-d)D(-u)E(-t)O
>  19. Oceanic country not essential to **Japanese city** (6) **NARUTO** = NA(-u)RU + TO
>  21. Two articles and novella exhausted **wise woman?** (6) **ATHENA** = A + THE + N_A
>  24. **Game** or conversation boring Mother, Billy, Iota, and yours truly (6,6,2) MORTAL KOMBAT II = M(ORTALK)OM + [BAT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/billy) + I (Iota) + I (yours truly)
>  26. America returning broken Mars probes filled with gas to Sweden becomes **game** (5,5,4.) **SUPER SMASH BROS** = US< + MARSPROBES* containing H (gas) + S (Sweden)
>
>  **Down:**
>  1. **Show** busy teachers around ferry (3,4,5) **THE CARE BEARS** = TEACHERS* around BEAR
>  2. I care about ***Stranger Things* character** (5) **ERICA** = ICARE*
>  3. Curtailed fish? Back to **meat alternative** (3) **NUT** = TUN(-a)<
>  4. Picked up pace to **tourist destination** (4) **ROME** = "ROAM" (using 'picked up' as a soundalike indicator) *(wordplay provided by @user39583 in comments)*
>  5. **RPG** from alert broadcast found in summit (9) **[DELTARUNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltarune)** = DUNE around ALERT*
>  6. **Start** petition now (5) **BEGIN** = BEG + IN
>  8. According to Spooner, all of us plant **algae** (7) **SEAWEED** = Spooner(“WE SEED”)
>  9. Without notice, sign follows need for **books** (12) **DICTIONARIES** = (-ad)DICTION + ARIES (sign)
>  11. Attorney general supported by current **Vice President** (5) **[AGNEW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiro_Agnew)** = AG + NEW
>  14. **Soviet scientist** put bits of eggplant and nutmeg in scrambled yolks (7)  **[LYSENKO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trofim_Lysenko)** = YOLKS* around (E_ + N_)
>  15. Discussions following electronic agreement lead to **natural protrusions** (9) **EYESTALKS** = E + YES + TALKS
>  16. **Turn** to celebrity head over heels (5) **PIVOT** = (TO + VIP)<
>  20. Hear about bathing time **early in the morning** (5) **[RATHE](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rathe)** = HEAR* around T
>  22. **Return** from garden terrace (5) **ENTER** = _EN TER_
>  23. **Epilogue** is improvised, written up without heart (4) **CODA** = AD(-h)OC<
>  25. **Scrooge says, "This** party? Pointless!" **BAH** = BA(-s)H

Next, note that...

> there are a lot of pop culture references here among the answers, not all of them explicitly mentioned as such in their clues. Moreover, it seems that many of these pop culture vehicles involve **characters who can control ice** (an appropriate quality for a 'seasonal' puzzle this *winter*...), with many of these fitting the formatting of the sequences of blanks beneath the crossword:
>
>  [KATAR**A**](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Katara) (10A Avatar: The Last Airbender)
>  [**N**OELLE HO**L**IDAY](https://deltarune.fandom.com/wiki/Noelle_Holiday) (5D Deltarune)
>  [SUB-**Z**ERO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Zero_(Mortal_Kombat)) (24A Mortal Kombat II)
>  [THE WH**I**TE WITCH](https://narnia.fandom.com/wiki/Jadis) (12A Narnia)
>  [H**A**KU](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Haku) (19A Naruto)
>  [**I**CE CLIM**B**ERS](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Ice_Climbers_(SSBU)) (26A Super Smash Bros.)
>  [P**R**OFESSOR COL**D**HEART](https://carebears.fandom.com/wiki/Professor_Coldheart) (1D The Care Bears)
>  [FRO**Z**ONE](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Frozone) (1A The Incredibles)

If we take the highlighted letters from the blank sequences and rearrange them, we can find 'a magical place to be with these sorts of characters':

> **IN A BLIZZARD!**
>
>  <sub>(Thanks to @JeremyDover in comments for being my sounding board and for pointing out the final anagram that I had originally completely overlooked for some more bizarre options!)</sub>

Comment: From the flavor, I feel like the next step is to rot13(svyy va punenpgref sebz gur tnzrf/fubjf/zbivrf va gur tevq. Sbe rknzcyr, IVBYRG be IRPGBE pbhyq pbzr sebz Gur Vaperqvoyrf; GUR JUVGR JVGPU sebz Aneavn; VPR PYVZOREF sebz Fhcre Fznfu Oebf). But I'm not familiar enough with all of these to push this any further. Or I'm completely wrong.

Comment: @JeremyDover That might be a good shout. Many of the answers here which were not clued in a pop culture way are also the names of pop culture vehicles...

Comment: Also it seemed like there might be a rot13(pbybe gurzr. IVBYRG sebz Vaperqvoyrf, JUVGR JVGPU sebz Aneavn, naq WNQR sebz Zbegny Xbzong. Ohg pbhyqa'g znxr vg jbex nal shegure...svtherq vg'f zl vtabenapr bs guvf nern bs cbc phygher.)

Comment: @JeremyDover Potentially. rot13(Gurer zvtug rdhnyyl or fbzrguvat 'grzcrengher-qrcraqrag' - jvgu punenpgref yvxr Sebmbar sebz Gur Vaperqvoyrf, naq Fho-Mreb sebz ZXVV, juvpu zvtug svg jvgu n jvagre gurzr...)

Comment: I think you've got it...that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: ^ In fact I'm pretty sure this is it... I've found plenty of others now!

Comment: It's probably rot13(va n oyvmmneq).

Comment: @JeremyDover Hahaha! How did I not see that?! (facepalm) I bet you are right! One more edit before bed...

Comment: Great work Stiv and @JeremyDover! As you mentioned, 4D isn't quite right (if you need a hint, V jnfa'g fher ubj snve guvf pyhr jnf, ohg gur jbeqcynl qbrfa'g hfr bgure ynathntrf), and there's also an issue with the explanation for 7A. As is, this answer is definitely qualified for the bounty, and I can patch up these last few tweaks after a while if no one wants to take a crack at them. (I'll wait to award the checkmark for a bit to indicate there's a bit more to do unless that's bad form, especially for the event.)

Comment: I was worried that the flavourtext was misleading at first ("zntvpny" jnf fhccbfrq gb or na nantevaq, nygubhtu abj V frr ubj vg tnir gur jebat vqrn ng svefg) but I'm glad you both made it there in the end!

Comment: @samm82 Yeah, no matter how much I look I'm still not seeing 4D then! Hopefully a passer-by might be able to spot it :) (Pretty sure I've now fixed my typo and subsequent misexplanation in 7A at least...)

Comment: A couple of quick comments: rot13(26N: Znlor crqnagvp, ohg V guvax gur jbeqcynl pbagnvaf U (svyyrq jvgu tnf) naq gura vf sbyybjrq ol F (gb Fjrqra). 4Q: pbhyq "cvpxrq hc" ersre gb BE<? Guvf fgvyy yrnirf trggvat ZN be ZR bhg bs cnpr, juvpu V pna'g svther).

Comment: rot13(V guvax cvpxrq hc vf n ubzbcubar vaqvpngbe sbe ebnz -> ebzr)

Comment: @JeremyDover Re 26A: Ah yes, my mistake. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: @user39583 Ha, I was so set on 'picked up' being a reversal indicator I totally overlooked that other potential meaning! That looks right to me - thanks very much!

Comment: Gorgeous work team, and right on the money @user39583!

Comment: Final observation: for 24A, rot13([ovyyl](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/billy) vf n glcr bs ong)

Comment: @samm82 Ha, that would be simpler - I assumed because of some of the other content that there was an anime connection!